# how can i get the API's SWAGGER?

Tags: .net-core, abp

I am using ABP for Net-Core.

Now I want to do

1. create a common named ApplicationCommon
2. move the Api of
   [Accounts], [Configuration], [Sessions] from Application to
   ApplicationCommon

I had done it and can run the API and show the swagger page.
But in the swagger page, I Cannot get the Api of [Accounts], [Configuration], [Sessions].

Why?
How can I do?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you looking for swagger API documentation for your application?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.